# Struts redirect with params

Tags: struts-1

I'm using struts 1.2.4 but I have a need to redirect with parameters from an Action Servlet to a target page.  I'm not able to upgrade to 1.2.7+ struts, so I'm not able to take advantage of `ActionRedirect`.

Right now the save() method in my action class returns an `ActionForward`

```
    return (mapping.findForward("success"));
}
```

which is mapped to this entry in struts-config.xml

```
        <forward 
            name="success" 
            path="/enterprise/company/searchCompany.do"/>
```

I'd actually like it the save() method to forward to something like '/enterprise/company/saveSurvey.do?companyID=1'  -- the value of companyID is available to my action class's save method.

What is the best way to accomplish redirect with param if I'm not able to upgrade Struts to take advantage of `ActionRedirect`?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 variants, but I am definitely have low knowledge in that area.

First:
You can save you params in Map and then in session, and after that you can load them

```
public ActionForward execute (HttpServletRequest request, ....){
  Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
  params.put("companyId","1");
request.getSession().setAttribute("PARAM_MAP",params);
   return (mapping.findForward("success"));
}
```

In your other method you can get params from that map like

```
Map<String,String> map = (Map<String,String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("PARAM_MAP");
```

The second variant is easier. You can use 1 form for both Actions and in struts.xml you have to point that

```
<form-beans>
   <form-bean name="MyBeanForm" type="your.full.packet.path.MyBeanForm"/>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>

  <action path="searchCompany"
          name ="MyBeanForm"
          scope="session"
          type="enterprise.company.SearchCompanyAction" />


  <forward 
            name="success" 
            path="/enterprise/company/searchCompany.do"/>

</action-mappings>
```